Change home screen in expo-react-native-paper
I'm trying to write app using expo-react-native-paper (https://github.com/youzarsiph/expo-react-native-paper) as template.
All works perfect with adding new screens and navigating between them. But I'm stuck changing Home screen. Now after loading opens /(tabs)/index.tsx, but want /drawer/index.tsx
I checked all files and configs, but still don't understand, why app/(tabs)/_layout.tsx renders first?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
